# Can we create local environments without the use of functions in Python?

Tags: python, environment-variables

Variables inside a function are deleted once the function execution is completed

But can we create such local environments without the use of functions?

This way, unnecessary variables can be easily deleted when their use is over

Edit: I'm talking about a syntax like that of with statements

For example, in the following code, I would like it if the variable `line` is deleted after exiting the with statement

```
with open("Text.txt") as f:
    line = f.readline()
    if line == "":
        break
    else:
        print(line)
```

Edit:

What I was asking for was a Python version of the C syntax:

```c
{
  int a = 5;
}
{
  char a = 'A';
}
```

But as @TimRoberts said, I realised it is a better coding practice to just write functions instead, even if I do not intend to call them more than once.

Comment: Just use [`del`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement)...

Comment: Python is using reference counting to free up memory after variables are no longer mentioned in the program

Comment: *Why* would you even want to avoid using functions here?  What down-side do you think they might have?

Comment: @MattDMo That's tiresome. Usually, I avoid creating such variables. But if I could create local environments, I can freely use more variables and improve readability

Comment: You seem to be looking for a way to avoid structured programming.  We've known for more than 60 years that organizing code into functions produces better programs.

Comment: @TomerPoliakov I am talking about the variable itself, not the memory

Comment: You could put your variables in a `dict` and `del` the `dict` when you are done. This is basically what class instances do.

Comment: Then what's the point?  Variables are just names.

Comment: @jasonharper I am talking about cases when I don't need to repeat the code more than once. Giving a function a name and then having to call the function for it to get executed, was what I was thinking about

Comment: @TimRoberts Well, only if the references get deleted first, the garbage collector would free up the memory

Comment: of coarse ... you can just put a bunch of code on lines and not make any functions (its unlikely that you can get away without calling any functions) ... `x=5` there ive created a variable out of the scope of any functions that should be globably accessible (within this file, or any that imports it from this file)

Comment: If you're concerned about reusing a variable, you can totally do that, if you do ``a = 1`` an later ``a = 2`` if you do ``print(a)`` the output will be ``2``. regardless there is really no reason to avoid using functions, performance-wise, the compromise is only about a few milliseconds a 1000+ calls besides they allow you to write less,  maintain your code easier and keep it more organized

Comment: @JoranBeasley I wasn't talking about global variables... But yeah, I think I should just use functions as Tim said

Answer (score 0):

If you want to encapsulate your data for easy deletion but don't want to use functions, another container like a `dict` or class instance can be used. Its not something you'd bother with unless you really need to get rid of resources. These examples aren't that.

dict:

```
data = {}
data["foo"] = 1
data["bar"] = 2
data["baz"] = 3
print(data["foo"] + data["bar"] + data["baz"])
del data
```

class:

```
class MyStruct:
    pass

data = MyStruct()
data.foo = 1
data.bar = 2
data.baz = 3
print(data.foo + data.bar + data.baz)
del data
```